# What's the right code to use to have a Discord bot reply with an array of alternative responses to one command, but it a random order?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been looking everywhere, searching all over the web, and no matter what I do, I just can't seem to get it working. The code I have here works, but adding any more than two replies doesn't work:

```js
client.on('message' , function (message){
    if (message.content == 'hi') 
    {
        var roll =(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1);
        if (roll == 1)
        {
            message.reply('hello');
        }
        else
        {
            message.reply('hey');
        }
```

I want to be able to add more replies than just this

Thanks

edit: I've just noticed another problem where my bot says all available replies on command, instead of just one at random. How do I fix this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend making an array of responses, and then choosing a random element from that array:

```js
// inside the 'message' event handler
const responses = ["Hey", "Hi", "Hello", "Hey"];

const randomResponse = responses[Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length)];

message.reply(randomResponse);
```

Since we're using `responses.length` while determining a random array index, all you have to do to add a new response to the pool is add to the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need an array of possible responses and a function that can get a random element from it. For example, this one:

```js
function randomElementOf(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
}
```

And use it to get a response from the array. Like this:

```js
const responses = ["hello", "hey", "hi", "sup"]; 
// ...
message.reply(randomElementOf(responses));
```